# Error "Failed to link org/apache/../CXFServlet" while deploying application on wildfly 10

Tags: java, deployment, wildfly

I'm Getting the following exception during application deployment.

`Failed to link org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/CXFServlet`

Stack Trace information below:

```
13:08:24,203 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment unico.ear
13:08:24,212 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Failed to define class org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet in Module "org.apache.cxf.impl:main" from local module loader @1c2c22f3 (finder: local module finder @18e8568 (roots: C:\tools\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules,C:\tools\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.NoC
lassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/CXFServlet (Module "org.apache.cxf.impl:main" from local module loader @1c2c22f3 (finder: local module finder @18
e8568 (roots: C:\tools\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules,C:\tools\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))): org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
13:08:24,216 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."unico.ear"."unico-services.war".POST_MODULE: o
rg.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."unico.ear"."unico-services.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeploym
ent "unico-services.war" of deployment "unico.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/CXFServlet (Module "org.apache.cxf.impl:main" from local module loader @1c2c22f3 (finder:
 local module finder @18e8568 (roots: C:\tools\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules,C:\tools\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))): org/springframework/context/ApplicationList
ener
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
        ... 5 more
```

I have already added these dependencies to jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <!-- exclude-subsystems>
             <subsystem name="webservices" /> 
        </exclude-subsystems -->
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf" export="true">
                 <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF**" />
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf**" />
                </imports>
            </module>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" export="true">
              <imports>
                <include path="META-INF**" />
                <include path="META-INF/cxf**" />
            </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you find a solution? I encounter similar problem.